# How to compare the custom validation type with itself in Joi?

Tags: javascript, validation, datetime

I need to validate the object with Joi that has two keys, `start` and `end`, which are date strings in `YYYY-MM-DD` formats.

The validation rules I need for this object is:

- each field is optional
- if provided, each field should a valid date (see `isValidDate`)
- `end` should be the date after the `start` (if both `end` and `start` are provided)

Joi doesn't provide the custom validations for date comparison without time, so I needed to extend it, here is my solution:

```
const date = Joi.extend({
    base: Joi.string(),
    name: 'string',
    language: {
        isValidDate: 'is not a valid date'
    },
    rules: [{
        name: 'isValidDate',
        validate(params, value, state, options) {
            if (!moment(value, 'YYYY-MM-DD', true).isValid()) {
                return this.createError('date.isValidDate', { v: value }, state, options);
            }

            return value;
        }
    }, {
        name: 'isDateAfter',
        params: {
            another: Joi.string().required() // This is where I'm stuck
        },
        validate(params, value, state, options) {
            if (!moment(value, 'YYYY-MM-DD', true).isAfter(params.another, 'day')) {
                return this.createError('date.isValidDate', { v: value }, state, options);
            }

            return value;
        }
    }]
});
```

My schema is described like that:

```
Joi.object({
    start: datetime.string().isValidDate(),
    end: datetime.string().isValidDate()
        .isDateAfter(Joi.ref('start', { default: '0000-00-00' }))
}).optional()
```

If I run this, I'll get an error:

```
ValidationError: {
  "another" [1]: "[ref:start]"
}

[1] "another" must be a string

103 |                     start: datetime.string().isValidDate(),
104 |                     end: datetime.string().isValidDate()
> 105 |                         .isDateAfter(Joi.ref('start', { default: '0000-00-00' }))
106 |                 }).optional()
```

How can I compare the 'end' key with the 'start' key if they are the same type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

I've found that there's an extension to compare date, from the maintainers of Joi itself, called `joi-date-extensions`. So I can easily compare dates without custom validations, like that:

```
date: Joi.object({
    start: Joi.date().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    end: Joi.date().format('YYYY-MM-DD').min(Joi.ref('start', { default: '0000-00-00' }))
}).optional()
```